# Undefined variable while calling a function that executes query

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable”  and “Notice: Undefined index”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

This must be something simple...

This script calls a db_prcislo() function.

```
<?php 
  require_once "kniznica/vyk/uzivatel_vyk.php"; db_prcislo();
  echo '<select name="problem_cislo">';
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($vysledok)){
   echo "<option value='".$row['problem_cislo']."'>".$row['problem_cislo']."</option>";} 
  echo "</select>";
?>
```

This is the db_prcislo() function

```
function db_prcislo() {
$poziadavka = "SELECT problem_cislo FROM problem_cislo";
$vysledok = mysql_query($poziadavka);
return $vysledok;}
```

Yet, I am getting undefined variable.

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: vysledok in C:\wamp\www\intranet_pre_ikeacmpts\pridatartikel.php on line 24

Comment: In the first block, you are not assigning any value to `$vysledok` before using it in `mysql_fetch_array`. In addition to that, please stop writing new code with the ancient mysql_* functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: you are not storing the value returned by the function,try this $vysledok=db_prcislo();

Answer (score 0):

The error is occurring because you're trying to use the variable `$vysledok` in your `while()` loop, but you never assigned it. You only assigned it in your `db_prcislo()` function.

Update to this and it should work:

```
<?php 
  require_once "kniznica/vyk/uzivatel_vyk.php";

  $vysledok = db_prcislo();
  echo '<select name="problem_cislo">';
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($vysledok)){
   echo "<option value='".$row['problem_cislo']."'>".$row['problem_cislo']."</option>";} 
  echo "</select>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything with the return value from `db_prcislo`.

Instead of

```
db_prcislo();
```

you should have

```
$vysledok = db_prcislo();
```

Comment: I will mark this as an answer... Need to get some sleep.

Answer (score 0):

You must retrieve the result of your function call:

Replace:

```
db_prcislo();
```

With:

```
$vysledok = db_prcislo();
```